# Is there any way to exclude some hbm mappings files from session factory object definition?

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, spring.net

I've built an application based on Spring.NET/NHibernate with multi session factory objects.

and I'm putting all the hbm files in one assembly.

```
/Assembly/
....Database1
........abc.hbm.xml
....Database2
........xyz.hbm.xml
```

I want to know is there any way to exclude hbm files for session factory object definition.

just like this (did you see the exclude tag?):

```
<object id="Db1SessionFactory" type=DataAccess.HibernateLocalSessionFactoryObject, DataAccess">
<property name="MappingAssemblies">
    <list>
         <value>DataAccess</value>
         <exclude>xyz.hbm.xml</eclude>
    </list>
</property>
```

Or..., maybe you can help me by some other solutions? plus, I don't want to seperate hbm files into several assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go the exclude way, because that would require you to change all configuration files in production when you add mapping files for "database 3". A better way would be to specifically *include* the (directory of) the mappings the session factory requires.

That being said, you can implement your own `SessionFactoryObject` inheriting from `LocalSessionFactoryObject` that takes an assembly and (for instance) a namespace or folder to load assemblies from. For an example on how to create your own `SessionFactoryObject` with custom configuration, you can have a look [at Benny Michielsen's one for FluentNHibernate](http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2009/01/04/using-fluent-nhibernate-in-spring-net/).

Edit ... it might look like this (untested!)

```
public class LoadMappingsFromFolderInAssemblySessionFactoryObject
              : LocalSessionFactoryObject
{
    // inject with the name of the assembly to load
    public string MyMappingAssembly { get; set; }
    // inject with the path to the folder within the assembly
    public string MyFolder { get; set; }

    protected override void PostProcessConfiguration(Configuration config)
    {
        base.PostProcessConfiguration(config);
        // snip ... guard methods omitted
        Assembly asm = GetAssembly(MyMappingAssembly);
        IEnumerable<string> paths = GetResourcePaths(MyFolder, asm);
        config.AddResources(paths, asm);
    }
    // snip ...
}
```

Comment: Marjin, thanks for you tips. but we use spring framework for nhibernate session management. we do implment multi SessionFactoryObject for each database, and due to we place all the hbm files in one assembly, all the SessionFactoryObjects can see them. it's bad, we need to make SessionFactoryObject know which    hbm file was belong to itself.

Comment: Well, I think you could quite easily do just that with the approach I outlined above. Let me see if I can quickly give you an example.

Comment: Yes, I saw that the key point was PostProcessConfiguration, I'm going to dig it. thanks.